# Custom URL on link to node

Tags: views, nodes, uri, redirection

I've got a field (URL) which contains a custom external URL for each node.
My goal is to set this custom url as link on the title which is displayed in a View. This is currently linked to a detail page (mydomain/node/5).

Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the node title as a token on the link-field (in the content type field settings).

You can alternatively output the field in the view as url plain text and rewrite the title to display as a link with the given field link as URL.